# Different answer based on the arithmetic type used (no overflow occuring)

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function in a generic class that calculates a determinant of a matrix. The function works for some inputs with any type, and for others it gives the wrong answer (based on the type).

Here is the function:

```
    public T Determinant()
    {
        checked
        {
            int n = dimension;
            Matrix<T> a = new Matrix<T>(baseArray);
            int i, j, k;
            T det = (dynamic)0;
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    det = (dynamic)a[j, i] / a[i, i];
                    for (k = i; k < n; k++)
                        a[j, k] = a[j, k] - (dynamic)det * a[i, k];
                }
            }
            det = (dynamic)1;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                det = (dynamic)det * a[i, i];

            return det;
        }
    }
```

I added the `checked` block to see if there was an overflow taking place, but apparently, there is no overflow happening.

A sample input is if the baseArray is `new double[,] {{11, 11, 12, 17, 21, 29}, {16, 9, 25, 30, 29, 33}, {3, 13, 9, 24, 21,
   24}, {23, 6, 29, 21, 23, 23}, {22, 19, 14, 30, 21, 24}, {22, 28, 
  20, 17, 25, 28}};` it will give the right answer (very close to -942755), but if baseArray is instead `new int[,] {{11, 11, 12, 17, 21, 29}, {16, 9, 25, 30, 29, 33}, {3, 13, 9, 24, 21,
   24}, {23, 6, 29, 21, 23, 23}, {22, 19, 14, 30, 21, 24}, {22, 28, 
  20, 17, 25, 28}};` it gives 15934050 as the answer (not even close).

The indexer on the matrix just returns the i-th j-th elements of the matrix, so they are not the issue.

I'm baffled as to what the issue could be since it is not an overflow. Any ideas?

**Code to reproduce:**

```
public class Matrix<T>
where T : IConvertible
{
    private int dimension;
    private T[][] baseArray;

    public Matrix(int dimensions, T[,] baseArray)
    {
        this.dimension = dimensions;
        this.baseArray = new T[dimension][];
        for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
        {
            this.baseArray[i] = new T[dimension];
            for (int j = 0; j < dimension; j++)
            {
                this[i, j] = baseArray[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    public T this[int a, int b]
    {
        get
        {
            return baseArray[a][b];
        }
        set
        {
            baseArray[a][b] = value;
        }
    }

    public T Determinant()
    {
        checked
        {
            int n = dimension;
            Matrix<T> a = new Matrix<T>(baseArray);
            int i, j, k;
            T det = (dynamic)0;
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    det = (dynamic)a[j, i] / a[i, i];
                    for (k = i; k < n; k++)
                        a[j, k] = a[j, k] - (dynamic)det * a[i, k];
                }
            }
            det = (dynamic)1;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                det = (dynamic)det * a[i, i];

            return det;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon is of course correct. Clearly you get different results when dividing integers by integers and doubles by doubles. What I don't understand is *why is there any division in this algorithm in the first place*? The determinant can be calculated using only addition, multiplication and subtraction.

Comment: @EricLippert, link to example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the values are `int` values, it performs integer arithmetic.
When the values are `double` values, it performs floating point arithmetic - it's as simple as that. Simpler example:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        PrintResult(1, 2);      // Prints 0
        PrintResult(1.0, 2.0);  // Prints 0.5
    }

    static void PrintResult(dynamic x, dynamic y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x / y);
    }
}
```

Comment: ouch, totally forgot about that.